# Which copy/move constructor/operator to define for simple structures?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-semantics, assignment-operator

My program uses a simple structure `Rect` which is defined as

```
struct Rect {
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;

    Rect()
    : x1(0), y1(0), x2(0), y2(0) { }

    Rect(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    : x1(x1), y1(y1), x2(x2), y2(y2) { }
};
```

Should I define a copy/move constructor or an assignment operator, or can I rely on the compiler to auto-generate those? The question is in context of speed and usage reasons (eg. a move constructor can influence program execution speed).

The constructors and operator are very repetitive work, so it'll be nice if I can rely on the compiler to generate them automatically.

```
    Rect(const Rect& r)
    : x1(r.x1), y1(r.y1), x2(r.x2), y2(r.y2) { }

    Rect(Rect&& r)
    : x1(r.x1), y1(r.y1), x2(r.x2), y2(r.y2) { }

    Rect& operator = (const Rect& r) {
        x1 = r.x1;
        y1 = r.y1;
        x2 = r.x2;
        y2 = r.y2;
    }
```

Comment: You should let the compiler generated constructors and assignment operators do their job since your class doesn't have to do any resource management. But there isn't anything to be gained from a move constructor or assignment operator in your case.

Comment: As your class doesn't have any pointers (which might have led to potential side effects), it seems the default ones should be okay.

Comment: You should totally let the compiler do it. It's guaranteed to be correct, whereas your manual code is not: for example, `operator =` should `return *this;`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Q1: Can you rely on the compiler to auto-generate those?*

Yes (in your example). See the C++11 Standard (clause 12), or the article [Implicit Move Won’t Go!](http://mmocny.wordpress.com/2010/12/09/implicit-move-wont-go/) (nice diagram near the end). To sum up (and simplify), all the following special member functions will be auto-generated (implicitly declared and defined as defaulted):

- *Destructor* – because you didn't declare it.
- *Copy Constructor* – because you didn't declare it nor any of MC and MAO.
- *Copy Assignment Operator* – because you didn't declare it nor any of MC and MAO.
- *Move Constructor* – because you didn't declare it nor any of D, CC, CAO and MAO.
- *Move Assignment Operator* – because you didn't declare it nor any of D, CC, CAO and MC.

(I used ugly initials only to keep the list items one line each.) In addition to the "because"s above, for all but the Destructor there's the additional constraint that the generated defaults *must make sense*, i.e. all the data members must be copyable (for the CC and CAO) or movable (for the MC and MAO). (Actually the precise rules are a bit more complicated, but I don't want to rephrase the Standard here.)

*Q2: Are the auto-generated functions correct?*

Yes (in your example). All your data members (here plain `int`s) have correct copy/move semantics (*their* copy/move constructors and assignment operators do the right thing, and those auto-generated for `Rect` will call them).

*Q3: Anyway, should you define them manually?*

I see no advantage to it (in your example), and potential issues (as in your example, see comments).

Comment: Regarding Q3: even if there are no specific semantics you wish to implement, you may wish to define those; for example, I commonly define Copy and Move operations in the `protected` section of a base class to prevent unintentional object slicing. In those cases, it is best to use the `= default` definition.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The `= default` is important indeed (so you still don't need to write their body; in your case it simply changes their accessibility from the default `public` to lesser). I think the Standardese for this is that they become _user-declared_ but not _user-provided_.

Answer (score 1):

You can relay on the compiler as your data members are built-in types so a copy of your object may be created via memberwise copy. This is the case if you don't define copy/move constructor nor an assignment operator. You may need them if you had a pointer as your data member.

Comment: This is a bit misleading. One could conclude that it only works because the members are built-ins, but this should work for well-designed user defined types too.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to write a explicit copy constructor a assignment for that your struct Rect's members are all c++ buildin type, so the compiler would generate a bitwise copy constructor.In your code, I think you can rely on your compiler completely.

Comment: See my comment to @cpp's answer: it is not restricted to built-in types and bitwise copies.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be verbose for some reasons, you may declare them as default to be self documented like this :

```
struct Rect {
    int x1, y1, x2, y2;

    Rect () : Rect( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) { }

    Rect ( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2 )
    : x1(x1), y1(y1), x2(x2), y2(y2) { }

    // Rect is Copy/Move Constructible and Assignable
    Rect( Rect const & ) = default;
    Rect( Rect && ) = default;
    Rect& operator= ( Rect const & ) = default;
    Rect& operator= ( Rect && ) = default;
};
```

Also notes the default constructor reusing the full one thanks to delegate constructors